# Code explanation of the json11 library about implicit constructor

Tags: c++11, templates, decltype

I'm reading the source code of the [main json11 header file](https://github.com/dropbox/json11/blob/master/json11.hpp).

It contains the following declaration:

```
template <class T, class = decltype(&T::to_json)>
Json(const T & t) : Json(t.to_json()) {}
```

I'm trying to find some documentation about this usage of `decltype` and `class` inside a template declaration but no success.

Does this construction/usage has a name in C++? Any good reference about it?

Comment: Google "SFINAE".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's using [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) ("**S**ubstitution **F**ailure **I**s **N**ot **A**n **E**rror"), a common technique for advanced template stuff. In this case, it's used as a crude<sup>(1)</sup> test whether the type `T` has a function named `to_json`.

How it works: if the expression `T::to_json` is well-formed (there is something named `to_json` inside the type `T`), `decltype(T::to_json)` denotes a valid type and the constructor template can be used normally.

However, if `T::to_json` is ill-formed (i.e. if there is no `to_json` member inside `T`), it means substituting the template argument for `T` has failed. Per SFINAE, this is not an error of the entire program; it just means that the template is removed from further consideration (as if it was never part of the class).

The effect is thus that if type `T` has a member `to_json`, you can use an object of type `T` to initialise a `Json` object. If there is no such member in `T`, the constructor will not exist.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> I'm saying *crude* test because this only checks that `T` has such a member. It doesn't check that the member is a function which can be invoked without arguments and returns something another constructor of `Json` can accept. A tighter-fitting test might look something like this:

```
template <class T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<Json, decltype(std::declval<const T>().to_json())>::value>>
Json(const T & t) : Json(t.to_json()) {}
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98deade7d0e8a487)

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. How would you do a “clean” check? Is it possible to that cleanly at compile time?